# Fetch list of Categories in controller to populate select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

My site allows users to Upload Images. Now i want the users to be able to assign their Image to a Category.

I run a Categories Scaffold, but how do i fetch a list in my Def New function in my Controller  to populate my Select in the Image Upload Form?

Comment: I'm so confused with you, don't take me wrong, but one moment you answer other people questions and then you ask something which can be found in any 15 min introduction to Ruby.

Comment: hahaha :) I'm learning Ruby just now, and i don't know but i got stuck with this problem. I'm searching hours now, but cant find a Solution.

Comment: I don't speak German yet ;) And answer below is ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one :

```
def new 
  @categories = Category.all
end
```

@The Mini John,  you have to put this object in your form as well. If @categories object fetches multiple categories, it will show it in your form. 
why are you using input, you should use select directly.

```
<%= f.select :category, @categories, :prompt => "Select One" %>
```

Hope it will help. Thanks.

Comment: If i put then in my Upload Form this -> <%= f.input :category, :as => :select %>, it only show me Yes or No. I wan the Categories to appear.

Comment: I sent you a pull request on github. Please do the necessary changes as per my commit. Thanks

Comment: Rails Guy, i got through your Code and finally Learned how to get it right with the Categories. I'm searching on how to display on a Page the pins on a specific Category. For Example "@pins where category is @category=testcategory". Is there a short hand code <%= %> ??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33861/discussion-between-the-mini-john-and-rails-guy)